# Perl expression using a combination of hash and array

Tags: perl, reference

I have difficulty understanding a piece of code. The statement is:

```
push(@{$errorfile{$var}}, $filepath);
```

I believe that push is used to append a value to the end of an array. But the above expression is confusing me. There is a hash and there is a @ symbol being used(which is usually used with array names). In the beginning of the code the "errorfile" is declared as:

```
my %errorfile;
```

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: have you tried to use `Data::Dumper` to print out `%errorfile`? Something like `print "errorfile looks like " . Dumper ( %errorfile );`

Comment: `perldoc perlreftut` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: IIRC since perl-5.12 or so, it can be simplified to: `push $errorfile{$var}, $filepath;`, which might be easier to read.

Comment: Everyone is mentioning perl references, but they're also overlooking one other important, related topic:  autovivification.  If your code simply declares `my %errorfile`, followed by `push @{$errorfile{$var}}, $filepath` with no other initialization between the two, the push _autovivifies_ an array ref on the spot.

Answer (score 8):

`%errorfile` is a hash.

`$errorfile{$var}` is a (scalar) value in the hash, corresponding to the key `$var`. The value happens to be an array reference.

`@{$errorfile{$var}}` is the array the reference refers to.

Example initialization: `my %errorfile = (foo => [12, 34], bar => [56]);`. After `$var = "bar"; $filepath = "my/file.txt"; push(@{$errorfile{$var}}, $filepath);` `%errorfile` becomes `(foo => [12, 34], bar => [56, "my/file.txt"])`.

See more details in the [Perl References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) link posted by David W.

Some highlights:

- a `$scalar` variable holds a scalar value, which can be undef, and integer, a floating point number, a string or a reference.
- an `@array` variable holds an array, which is an indexable list of scalar values.
- a `%hash` variable holds a mapping from strings to scalar values.

So the only way to put an array to a hash is to put an array reference to a value within the hash.

Comment: you mean to say that errorfile is a hash that has a arrays as value?

Comment: is it then possible to have a hash value that itself is an array rather than being a reference to an array??

Comment: @RoyOneMillion: My answer already answer this (is it then possible to have a hash value that itself is an array rather than being a reference to an array?). The answer is no, because a hash value must be a scalar, and an array is not a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

```
my %errorfile;  # Declares a hash named errorfile

$errorfile{$var} # is reference to an array 
# This is probably used to store different flavors of error files.

@{$errorfile{$var}} # is the array which is referenced.  

# Let's call it @array = @{$errorfile{$var}}

push(@{$errorfile{$var}}, $filepath); # is similar to push(@array, $filepath);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to read about [Perl References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Standard Perl data types talk about single pieces of data. A scalar holds a single piece of data. Hashes and arrays hold a whole bunch of single pieces of data. However, what happens if you have something a bit more complex.

Imagine a car registration database. Cars have models, year, make, owners, etc. How would I have an *array* of cars which contain all of this data?

References get you around this limitation. For example, I might have a hash for a car that contains this information:

```
my %car;
$car{make} = "Yugo";
$car{year} = "1987";
$car{model} = "GV";
$car{owner} = "David";
$car{value} = "$0.02";
```

I can make a reference to this *car hash* by putting a backslash in front of it:

```
my $car_hash_reference = \%car;
```

My *reference* is just a point in memory where this *car hash* is stored. Now, I can push that car hash reference into an array of cars:

```
push @cars, $car_hash_reference;
```

Each entry in my `@cars` array is a reference to a hash that is about a particular car. Each car has its owner, model, make, year, etc. When I pop off my car entry, I get that reference back:

```
my $car = pop @cars;   # Reference to a car
```

I can *dereference* my reference by putting the `%` hash sigil back in front of it:

```
my %car_hash = %{ $car };
```

And, now I can print out the make and owner:

```
print "The owner of the $car_hash{make} is $car_hash{owner}\n";
```

In other words, instead of each entry of my `@cars` array storing only a single piece of data, each entry in `@cars` now contains all the information about this particular car.

Let's look at the line of code you were having troubles understanding. I added some spaces to make it a bit easier to understand:

```
push ( @{ $errorfile{$var} }, $filepath );
```

`$errorfile{$var}` is a reference to an array. I can tell that because `@{ $errorFile{$var} }` dereferences it back into an array. Once it is dereferenced, you can *push* `$filepath` onto it just like a regular array.

It looks like `%errorfile` is a hash and each entry in that hash contains references to an array of `$filepath`s.

Answer (score 0):

This might clarify it further, because it shows the basic use of references to arrays. However, you really ought to consult the perlreftut.

```
my @your_array = ("Hello"); 
my $ref = \@your_array; 
print @{$ref}[0];
```

$ref is an reference to @your_array

And @{$scalar_with_reference} is just the syntax of how you access the array your reference is pointing to.